# Spring integration Tcp Server timeout with custom deserializer

Tags: kotlin, tcp, deserialization, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am declaring a Tcp inbound adapter to receive messages from a specific client, a hardware device that sends a custom payload. There isn't a default deserializer that fits my needs for the message sent by the client, so I implemented a custom one that reads the input stream if there is anything to read and I process the payload after in other component of the chain, also I use an interceptor to only accept the non empty payloads.

My issue is that I need to close the connection with a timeout, but with the soTimeOut set up, the connection isn't closed after the specified timeout. I suspect is because the deserializer detects the empty input stream and consider the empty message a valid one.

This is the server configuration using Kotlin DSL

```
@Bean
    fun tcpServer() = Tcp.netServer(port)
        .leaveOpen(true)
        .deserializer { inputStream ->
            when(inputStream.available()>0){
                true -> inputStream.readNBytes(inputStream.available())
                false -> byteArrayOf()
            }
        }
        .serializer(TcpCodecs.raw())
        .backlog(30)
        .interceptorFactoryChain(interceptor())
        .soTimeout(60000)
```

This is the interceptor to filter the non empty payloads for further processing

```
class ValidationInterceptor(
    applicationEventPublisher: ApplicationEventPublisher
) : TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport(applicationEventPublisher) {
    override fun onMessage(message: Message<*>): Boolean {
        if ((message.payload as ByteArray).isEmpty()) return false
        return super.onMessage(message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question with the solution that I have found.

I solved my issue with another interceptor that launch a Kotlin coroutine with a timeout, once the timeout is completed the connection is closed manually. If a message arrives the coroutine is restarted. The sample code is the following:

```kotlin
class ConnectionTimeoutInterceptor(
    applicationEventPublisher: ApplicationEventPublisher,
) : TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport(applicationEventPublisher) {

    private val timeoutMillis: Long = 600000
    private lateinit var timeoutJob: Job
    init {
        startTimeout()
    }
    override fun onMessage(message: Message<*>): Boolean {
        resetTimeout()
        return super.onMessage(message)
    }

    private fun startTimeout() {
        timeoutJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            delay(timeoutMillis)
            close()
        }
    }
    private fun resetTimeout() {
        timeoutJob.cancel("Received message timeout stopped")
        startTimeout()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, share with us how you close the socket.
An `soTimeout` does not close the socket:

```
/**
 *  Enable/disable {@link SocketOptions#SO_TIMEOUT SO_TIMEOUT}
 *  with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set
 *  to a positive timeout value, a read() call on the InputStream associated with
 *  this Socket will block for only this amount of time.  If the timeout
 *  expires, a <B>java.net.SocketTimeoutException</B> is raised, though the
 *  Socket is still valid. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 *  The option <B>must</B> be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation
 *  to have effect.
 *
 * @param timeout the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
 * @throws  SocketException if there is an error in the underlying protocol,
 *          such as a TCP error
 * @throws  IllegalArgumentException if {@code timeout} is negative
 * @since   1.1
 * @see #getSoTimeout()
 */
public synchronized void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException {
```

Plus you use that `.leaveOpen(true)`. So, to have socket closed you must do `TcpConnection.close()` manually some way.
For example, an `AbstractConnectionFactory.closeConnection(String connectionId)` API can be used from some of your code where you take `IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID` header from a message you receive on that TCP server socket.

Comment: I do not close the socket manually, I was wondering if there is a way that the server closes the connections after a specified amount of time if it does not receive any message.

Comment: Now you know that it does not. You did everything to not have that connection closed.